# How do i continuously stream data from kafka using spark structured streaming?

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to migrate my DStream api's to strucutred streaming and tumbling upon how to await or not able to correlate microbatching with structured streaming.

In the below code am creating direct stream and awaiting forever so that i could consume kafka messages indefinitely.

How can i achieve the same in structured streaming ?

does sparkSession.streams.awaitAnyTermination will suffice ?

I have put a sample code below in both streaming , structured streaming . Any pointers would be much helpful .Thank you

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
        "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
        "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer], 
        "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
        "max.poll.records" -> "1",
        "group.id" -> "test",
        "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean))
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(10))
      val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc,  PreferConsistent,Subscribe[String, String]("mytopic",kafkaParams))

performRddComputation(stream, sparkSession)

 ssc.start()
 ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**Structured streaming equivalent**

```
val df = sparkSession
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("kafkfa.offset.strategy","latest")
      .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
      .load()
      df.printSchema()

      val tdf = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String].select("value").writeStream.format("console")
    .option("truncate","false")
    .start()


    tdf.map(record =>  {//do something})

      sparkSession.streams.awaitAnyTermination
```

Answer (score 1):

I will post a version that work with me:

```
val df = sparkSession
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("kafkfa.offset.strategy","latest")
  .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
  .load()
  //df.printSchema()

  val tdf = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    .select("value")
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate","false")
    .start()
  tdf.awaitAnyTermination()
```

It should work for you

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one query, just use `awaitTermination` on the query:

```
val df = sparkSession
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("kafkfa.offset.strategy","latest")
      .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
      .load()
      df.printSchema()

val tdf = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]
    .select("value")
    .map(record =>  {//do something})
    .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate","false")
    .start()

// do something

tdf.awaitTermination()
```

`awaitTermination` is a blocking call so anything you will write after that will only be called after the query is terminated.

If you need to handle more than one query you can use `awaitAnyTermination` on the `StreamingQueryManager`:

```
sparkSession.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

and if you want to keep the application running even if one of the query failed then call `awaitAnyTermination()` followed by `resetTerminated()` in a loop.